# How to get most efficient access to a table when querying based on almost all columns?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, indexing

My scenario is the following: I have a table with columns 1 through 8. Columns 1 - 7 are the "functional key" (int / string /date values), and column 8 stores a numeric value referenced by that key. There is also an ID field which is the technical key.

Now regularly I have to update/insert the values for a (potentially large, a.k.a. hundreds or even a few thousands entries) subset of the rows: Read the current value of a given key, do some basic calclulations, update the value in the DB (insert new row if no entry existed before). The whole thing is done via Hibernate and Oracle DB.

Is there any use for indexes here? If use an index for accessing, it would need all columns, and that is useless, right? Especially cause every value that was read is updated as well. But I am afraid without indexes the access can be very slow, especially since the table can grow very large (millions of entries). Data from the table that is older than a specified number of days (the date is part of the key columns).

Clarification: The read always reads exactly one entry and updats the value, it is always queried by the full combination of columns 1-7.

Comment: "I am afraid without indexes the access can be very slow" any chance of trying that out in a test DB? i.e. create the table with millions of dummy records, run your thing, see how long it takes, watch the plan, try the index, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with just the Primary Key index and see what are the most frequent queries that might benefit from an index.

Indexing all columns is not very practical. You can have an index with multiple columns that can serve as many queries as possible, and, if this is not enough, you can supply other indexes for other column combinations that can speed-up the remaining queries.

It all depends on your read patterns. If you modify all entries frequently, then many indexes will slow down the write operations. Nevertheless, they will speed-up the reading but only if the query filtering criteria is highly-selective. If a query needs to scan a large portion of the table, the index will be slower than a full-table scan, and so it will not be used in the execution plan.

If you can tolerate eventual consistency, you could also have a full-text search engine (Hibernate Search, ElasticSearch, SOLR) to serve read operations and update the full-text search engine incrementally and asynchronously. This way, the database will not need indexing since the read operations are done through the full-text search solution. The indexes will be stored in the full-text search engine, which can allow more free-text searches if that's what you need.

So, it all depends on your data access patterns.

Comment: What do you mean by "default primary key"? My technical PK on the table is the ID field, but this is not known for the queries. The queries always specify all values of column 1-7 and retrieve exactly one entry, or zero if not yet existing.

Comment: I removed the default to avoid confusions. Well, what do you think of the rest of the answer?

Comment: Full text search is not applicable I think cause it is mostly int values or short string identifiers. If I understand the other things correctly, you mean first index one or few columns that are most probably to distinguish the values and seeing how it behaves and potentially adding more columns? That sounds reasonable and will be my first try I guess, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a surrogate key, your ID field, which is acting as your primary key. You further have a natural key, the 7 columns, which are unique.

If you want to ensure that your natural key is always unique then you need to create a [unique constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datainte.htm#CNCPT1642) on those columns. You don't *need* your surrogate key if you're never going to be accessing the table using it. However, if you want this to act as a primary key you need to create a [primary key constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datainte.htm#GUID-E1033BB9-0F67-4E59-82AC-B8B572FD82BB) on that column.

Ignoring access paths, you *require* two indexes (indexes being created with the keys) for data integrity, so create them.

Don't worry about anything being "slow" until something actually is. I highly doubt that index maintenance will cause any noticeable difference when inserting or updating a few thousand rows. But, your queries will be much faster if you're updating a few thousand rows in a multi-million row table.

Indexes are used for data access paths, the fact that an entire table is an index doesn't change how the data is accessed. If you're selecting a single row from a table using a unique index then [that row will be accessed uniquely (an index unique scan), no matter how many columns there are in the index.](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys)

I would highly recommend reading [Use the index Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/table-of-contents).

Personally, I'd consider putting your 8th column in the index as well. As it stands, when you access rows down using your 7 column unique index you'll be doing an [index range scan](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optop.htm#TGSQL236) or [index unique scan](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optop.htm#TGSQL235) followed by a [table access by index rowid](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optop.htm#TGSQL232). This is because your 8th column is not in the index and so Oracle needs to re-access the table using the index in order to get the data you want returned. If the 8th column is also in the index then Oracle will not need to access the table at all. As ever YMMV and test to see what's best for your specific circumstances.